# REST - Enviar null para parâmetro Integer

Tags: java, rest, null, jax-rs

Tenho a seguinte situação no meu REST (Jersey):

URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/listar_log_utilizacao/null
```

Código:

```
@GET @Path("/listar_log_utilizacao/{idUsuario: .*}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response listarLogUtilizacao(@PathParam("idUsuario") Integer idUsuario) throws Exception  {
...
}
```

Valores inteiros são recebidos sem problemas, porém, nessa situação, o parâmetro é opcional e quando vem null como parâmetro dá erro 404...

Comment: Veja [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421104/optional-pathparam-in-jax-rs) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32765804/optional-params-in-rest-api-request-using-jersey-2-21/32778643#32778643). Creio que lhe sejam úteis. Agora, não entendi esse `null` como parâmetro.

Comment: Na verdade o null é originado no javascript e enviado à API via Axios... Na API (JAX-RS) o null se torna String e assim dá erro no parâmetro Integer que recebe o valor... Resolvi o problema criando uma classe Integer personalizada, que aceita null, 'null' e '

Answer (score -1):

Segue resolução:

```
@GET @Path("/listar_log_utilizacao/{idUsuario: .*}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response listarLogUtilizacao(@PathParam(“idUsuario”) IntegerParam idUsuario) throws Exception {
…
}
```

Classe Java:

```
public class IntegerParam implements IServer {
private Integer number = null;
public IntegerParam(String number) throws WebApplicationException {
try {
if ((number.equals(“null”)) || (number.isEmpty())) {
return;
}
// Converter String em Integer
if (util.isInteger(number)) {
this.number = util.toInt(number);
return;
}
} catch (Exception e) {
throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("Couldn’t parse to Integer: " + e.getMessage()).build());
}
}

public Integer getInteger() {
    return this.number;
}
```